# ImportError: cannot import name when using pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I am creating a directory structure in python that is similar to this:

```
module_root
├── __init__.py
├── module_a
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── local_module_a.py
│   └── tests
│       ├── context.py
│       └── test_local_module_a.py
├── module_b
│   └── tests
│       └── context.py
├── tests
│   ├── context.py
│   └── test_this_module_will_be_exported.py
├── this_module_will_be_exported.py
└── this_module_will_not_be_exported.py
```

Every module has their own test folder with their tests. Once Python doesn't search for modules in directories above file calling `import`, every test directory has a file called `context.py` that is similar to:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))

from this_module_will_be_exported import ThisClassWillBeExported
```

Then, inside each test file, I use the following import statement:

```
from context import ThisClassWillBeExported
```

Everything works fine when I have only one `test` directory with one `context.py`, but as I add more tests (like described in directory tree above), `pytest` execution returns the following error.

```
ImportError while importing test module 'path/to/module_root/tests/test_this_module_will_be_exported.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
module_root/tests/test_this_module_will_be_exported.py:1: in <module>
    from context import ThisClassWillBeExported
E   ImportError: cannot import name 'ThisClassWillBeExported'
```

When I change name of `module_root/module_a/tests/context.py` to `module_root/module_a/tests/_context.py` (for instance), tests work well. So I know that I can simply change all `context.py` to different names, but I want to keep their name to avoid more work.

So I need help of community, there are a way to keep `context.py` name and solve this problem?

Thanks. :)

Comment: It might be because you import classes with the same name to your current workspace. Maybe you should try it with full path eg; import module_a.tests.context instead of from module import class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to just add the root directory to `PYTHONPATH` not all the context files.

Secondly, try using relative paths instead, if you want to import context file from the same folder.

```
from .context import ThisClassWillBeExported
```

Thirdly, make sure all the context files have the variable you want to import.

Comment: I've set PYTHONPATH before run scripts and it worked. Thanks for the answer. :)